# On an example of a subet of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am struggling with the proof by contradiction that the following subset $X$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I would appreciate any explanation.

Let $$
X = ((-1,0] \times \{0\}) \cup (\{0\} \times [0, 1)) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2.
$$
Suppose $X$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
Suppose $(U, \phi)$ be a local chart of $\mathbb{R}^2$ around $(0,0)$ such that $\phi|_{U \cap X}$ maps $U \cap X$ homeomorphically onto $\phi(U) \cap (\mathbb{R} \times \{0\})$. WLOG let $\phi(0,0) = 0$. Let now $(U, id)$ be a local chart of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for its $C^{\infty}$ structure. Since $D(\phi \circ id^{-1})|_0$ is singular, it follows that $\phi \circ id^{-1}$ is not a diffeomorphism. Hence the local chart $(U, \phi)$
and $(U, id)$ are not $C^{\infty}$ compatible. Contradiction. $X$ is not a $C^{\infty}$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

1) How come we only need to consider the dimension $1$ case? How do we know that $X$ will not be of dim $0$ and $2$ submanifold?

2) How do I prove that $D(\phi \circ id^{-1})|_0$? I can see it, because it's turning an edge to a straight line, but I was wondering how can I prove this?

Comment: (1) The other points of $X$ clearly have one-dimensional neighborhoods; so if $X$ is going to be a manifold, it has to be one-dimensional.

Comment: Dimension 0 fails due to bijectivity. Dimension 2 fails because the image of open subsets of $X$ via a continous map cannot be open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (paths are mapped to paths). And together with injectivity, the path-connectedness is exactly the reason why $X$ fails to be a 1-dim topological manifold.

Comment: Ah. I've missed that's just a corner. Sorry.

Comment: It might be worth specifying: Endowed with the subset topology, this set *is* a *topological* submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$. That topological submanifold, however, does not admit a smooth structure compatible with the usual smooth structure on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: In detail, since $X$ can be covered by just one chart, there actually is a smooth structure. But it's not the standard structure mentioned by Travis. However, a dagger shaped subset would not even be a top. mfd. (for my own justification: that's what I thought first :P).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the parametrization $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to U$  given by $\gamma(t)=(0,t)$ (We can choose $\epsilon<1$ small enough, so that $(0,t)\in U$ for $-\epsilon<t<\epsilon$). Since $\gamma'(0)=(0,1)$, we have that  $$D(\phi\circ id^{-1})|_0(0,1)=\frac{d}{dt}(\phi\circ id^{-1}\circ\gamma(t))|_{t=0}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\phi(\gamma(t))}{t}$$
But, since $\gamma(t)\in X\cap U$ for $0<t<\epsilon$, we have that $\phi(\gamma(t))\in \phi(U)\cap\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}\subset \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}.$ In particular 
$$D(\phi\circ id^{-1})|_0(0,1)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\phi(\gamma(t))}{t}\in\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$$.

A similar approach, proves that $D(\phi\circ id^{-1})|_0(1,0)\in \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$. Since $(0,1);(1,0)$ is a basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$, this implies that the image of $D(\phi\circ id^{-1})|_0\subset\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ in particular is singular.